# What is the significance of dividing the euclidean metric by $\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

From Munkres Topology:[image]

---

---

In the above proof, I was trying to figure out where Munkres obtained the $\sqrt{n}$ and I think it was by dividing the sum of the squares by $n$ in the euclidean metric. Is this correct?

However, now I have the following concern:

What is the significance of the root mean square of the euclidean metric?

$$\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}{n}\right)^{1/2}$$

At first I thought it was probably the average of the distances between the coordinates but when I calculated an example in two dimensions, I saw this was not the case. For example, consider the points $(1,2)$ and $(7,11)$. We see $\sqrt{6^2+9^2}/2=\sqrt{117}/2 = 7.6485$. But the average of $6$ and $9$ is $7.5$.

So, what is the significance of dividing the euclidean metric by $\sqrt{n}$? What does this value represent?

---

I understand the heart of the proof, that is, why the topologies are the same. What I am asking is more of an intuitive question. What the calculation behind the proof means.

Comment: equivalent metrics produce the same topology. Equivalent means there are global positive constants, call them $0 < A < B,$ such that, for all pairs of points, we always get $A \rho < d < B \rho.$

Comment: $$\sum_{i = 1}^n (x_1 - y_i)^2 \leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^n (\max \{\lvert x_j - y_j\rvert : 1 \leqslant j \leqslant n\})^2 = \rho(x,y)^2\cdot \sum_{i = 1}^n 1$$

Comment: I understand what the proof is saying. I am concerned more about what the general calculation represents.

Comment: @DanielFischer Aren't you forgetting to square root?

Comment: A cube with side length $\ell$ is contained in a concentric ball with radius $\sqrt{n}\ell/2$, because the largest distance to the center within the cube is achieved at one of the corners and the maximum distance is precisely this value (use the distance formula).

Comment: @AlJebr I left it off for better typesetting. By applying the square root to both sides, you get $d(x,y) \leqslant \sqrt{n}\,\rho(x,y)$, as desired, and you can see exactly when you have equality in this.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt n$ is just the length of the diagonal of the $n$-cube: the above inequality just says that 
$$
\max_i \{ |y_i - x_i| \}  \leq \sqrt {\sum_i (y_i - x_i)^2} \leq \sqrt {\sum_i (\max_i \{ |y_i - x_i |\})^2} = \sqrt {n (\max_i \{ |y_i - x_i |\})^2} =
$$
$$
= \sqrt n \max_i \{ |y_i - x_i| \}
$$